# ASP.NET 5 Routing with AngularJS Routing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an  application with ASP.NET 5 with AngularJS. I'm using basic client side HTML routing support provided by Angular. I've successfully implemented Angular Routing, the default routing in Startup class is

```
app.UseMvc(routes => 
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Here is my Angular Routing

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'static/home.html',
        controller: 'AppController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'static/about.html',
        controller: 'AppController'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'static/contact.html',
        controller: 'AppController'
    }).
    when('/tutorial', {
        templateUrl: 'static/tutorial.html',
        controller: 'AppController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 }]);
```

It all works fine, but when I create another action in the same controller and wants to redirect to that action through URL, it redirect it to the same action i.e. Index

Here is my code for HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Web()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Routing happens in Index, but can't navigate to Web Action. What is the problem that I'm confronting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yaht the problem is that your application does not know anything about your `Web` method. To solve this you can:

1) use attribute routing, and

2) write direct route in your route configuration method.

Also check your `web.config` file for redirection in `rewrite` node of `system.webServer` section or any other redirection configurations

P.S. Be noted that if you redirects to another page your angular application will reconfigured and restarted. It takes some time. You should not use redirections ang all other page reloading methods if you want your app will be really cool. Try think in "angular" way. If you want to change part of the main content - angular will do it with routing. If you want to load some additional content and you want it looks like `http://host/controller/method/submethod1/submethod2` url in browser - angular also can do it for you. You just need to place `get()` method inside your angular controller as the first step. In this case when angular will be resolving this controller it calls your `get()` method and loads data from server. So, you will have fast apllication with actual content always.

P.P.S. Try to use `angular-ui-routing` instead of default `ng-route`. `ng-route` is good, but it can not support subrouting well and also it has some other issues. `angular-ui-routing` solves all these messy things

Comment: I've used Angular UI Routing, it works fine. But I lost pretty URLs for AngularJS. I've to make web.config available in my project to route to default home.html upon refresh. Is there any solution?

Comment: The main idea of angular routing engine is that its a client-side routing, not server-side. If you use default ngRoute you have one of the problems from the list of ngRoute problems - it always made url calls to server, so you need to disable this with rewrite rule in web config. And that's also why I suggested you use angular-ui-route plugin. In this case its unnecessary to disable server-side routing and you can reach all your server methods from your mvc controllers. I also use angularjs with asp.net mvc and I had the same issues like you now:)

Comment: By the way, if you want that your urls look like `http://host/sitename/path1/path2` instead of `http://host/sitename/#/path1/path2` while you're working with angular routing system you can enable html5Mode setting it in application config method of your angular module: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`. And of course do not forget to inject `$locationProvider` in config function. But, it turns the same: ngRoute holds this very bad in case of using it with mvc app. Trust me :) And I'm not promoting `ui-router` here

Comment: Actually, I'm confronting the problem, that is I've successfully solved the pretty URLs and Home/Web server side route using Route Attributes. But I can't go to the another action through ActionLink? It instead redirect it to the /home html page? Is there any solution? Thanks

Comment: If I'm right, you have redirection rule in your `web.config` file. If so you can't redirect properly to any url because your redirection rule works, and it always will redirect you to your redirection url. And Route cpnfiguration does not work in this case - redirection rule from `web.config` has the highest priority. If you want to be able to interact with other server-side you should not use any redirection rules

Answer (score 2):

Try this one to register your route,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then also try this below your config:

```
   .controller('RootController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $http) {

        $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, previous) {
            $scope.activeViewPath = $location.path();
        });

    }]);
```

Hope this will help. =)

Comment: I guess you don't need to add another action in your Home Controller. What kind of Angular Routing are you using? ng-route or ui-router?